# spring java mvc error handling

Tags: java, spring, web-services

im implementing a java web client which connects to two web services. so basically i have a table listing the status of these two web services. example:

```
<table>
<tr>
<th>webservice</th>
<th>status</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>webservice 1</td>
<td>connected</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>webservice 2</td>
<td>connected</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

my java controller:

```
class test {

 @autowired
 private WebServiceTemplate webservice1;
 @autowired
 private WebServiceTemplate webservice2;

 public String mycontroller(...) {
  webserviceReq request = new ObjectFactory().createwebserviceReq();
  webserviceRes response = new ObjectFactory().createwebserviceRes();

 try {
  response = (webserviceRes)this.webservice1.marshalSendAndReceive(webserviceReq);
  //...set all the data
 }
 catch(Exception e) {

 }

 try {
  response = (webserviceRes)this.webservice2.marshalSendAndReceive(webserviceReq);
  //...set all the data
 }
 catch(Exception e) {

 }
 }//end of function
}
```

if the connection to either webservice fails (mayb the webserivce crash or wat), show the status as disconnected.

currently the problem im facing is if either one connection fail, im getting http status 500, request processing failed.

how can i capture the connection failure for each webservice and print it into the  status column?

Comment: It depends on how you are currently checking the web service connection. Can you show the relevant pieces of code?

Comment: currently im using try and catch but im not sure how to throw the error from controller to view.

Comment: i updated my questions with java codes. hope its a little clearer how i am doing it.

Answer (score 0):

In each of the `catch` blocks, extract relevant parts of the `Exception` in order to determine the specific error. Add them to the returned `String`.

Things might get easier by not catching `Exception`, but a subclass that is specifically thrown by your webservices. These might contain the relevant error information.